# Snakemake pipeline not attempting to produce output?

Tags: snakemake

I have a relatively simple snakemake pipeline but when run I get all missing files for rule all:

> 

```
refseq = 'refseq.fasta'
reads = ['_R1_001', '_R2_001']

def getsamples():
    import glob
    test = (glob.glob("*.fastq"))
    print(test)
    samples = []
    for i in test:
        samples.append(i.rsplit('_', 2)[0])
    return(samples)

def getbarcodes():
    with open('unique.barcodes.txt') as file:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
    return(lines)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("grepped/{barcodes}{sample}_R1_001.plate.fastq", barcodes=getbarcodes(), sample=getsamples()),
        expand("grepped/{barcodes}{sample}_R2_001.plate.fastq", barcodes=getbarcodes(), sample=getsamples())
    wildcard_constraints:
        barcodes="[a-z-A-Z]+$"


rule fastq_grep:
    input:
        R1 = "{sample}_R1_001.fastq",
        R2 = "{sample}_R2_001.fastq"
    output:
        out1 = "grepped/{barcodes}{sample}_R1_001.plate.fastq",
        out2 = "grepped/{barcodes}{sample}_R2_001.plate.fastq"
    
    wildcard_constraints:
        barcodes="[a-z-A-Z]+$"
    shell:
        "fastq-grep -i '{wildcards.barcodes}' {input.R1} > {output.out1} && fastq-grep -i '{wildcards.barcodes}' {input.R2} > {output.out2}"
```

The output files that are listed by the terminal seem correct, so it seems it is seeing what I want to produce but the shell is not making anything at all.

I want to produce a list of files that have grepped the list of barcodes I have in a file. But I get "Missing input files for rule all:"

Comment: Have you made sure that the input files snakemake requires actually exist? Maybe there is a typo in the paths in your `Snakefile`?

Can you please edit your post and provide a working Snakefile for us to work with? Atleast the `rule fastq_grep` was split in your post and we do not know what the functions `getbarcods()` and `getsamples()` return as we don't have access to those files. Finally, please include how you call `snakemake` from the command line and if possible the full output from `Snakemake`.

Comment: @euronion 

I am new to this - "Well_211_S20_R1_001.fastq" , "Well_211_S20_R2_001.fastq"this is how all of the files are formatted.

Full error message


Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 19 of /mnt/25c0b307-c315-4339-b395-d9fef3b99d97/data/lucas/MOJGAN_RUNS_COPY_DIRECT/2022_091_Mojgan_Reza_REPEAT3/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/snakemake_test/old_snakemake/snakefile:
Missing input files for rule all:
grepped/CAATAGWell_211_S20_R1_001.plate.fastq
etc

I am simply running snakemake by typing "snakemake"

Comment: 'Well_202_S11_R1_001.fastq', 'Well_207_S16_R2_001.fastq', 'Well_200_S9_R2_001.fastq', 'Well_211_S20_R2_001.fastq',

This is the format that rule getsamples() returns

Comment: Thanks, this is already helpful. One is still missing: What does `getbarcods()` return? Can you give example data? I think there might be a conflict between the `{barcodes}` wildcard in `rule fastq_grep` and the `wildcards_constraints` for that wildcard.

Comment: @euronion

Yes that's my opinion as well! Just not sure where the conflict is... getbarcodes() just reads a file line by line and returns. Barcodes file looks like this:

AACGGT
ACTCTA
AGTACC
CAATAG
CCACGT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. You have an impossible `wildcard_constraints` defined for `{barcode}`
2. Your two wildcards `{barcode}` and `{sample}` are competing with each other.

Remove the `wildcard_constraints` from your two rules and add the following lines to the top of your `Snakefile`:

```py
wildcard_constraints:
    barcodes="[A-Z]+",
    sample="Well.*",
```

The constraint for `{barcodes}` now only matches capital letters. Before it also included end-of-line matching (trailing `$`) which was impossible to match for this wildcard as you had additional text in the filepath following.

The constraint for `{sample}` ensures that the path of the filename starting with "Well..." is interpreted as the start of the `{sample}` wildcard. Else you'd get something unwanted like `barcode=ACGGTW` instead of `barcode=ACGGT`.

A note of advice:
I usually find it easier to seperate wildcards into directory structures rather than having multiple wildcards in the same filename. In you case that would mean having a structure like
`grepped/{barcode}/{sample}_R1_001.plate.fastq`.

Full suggested `Snakefile` (formatted using [`snakefmt`](https://github.com/snakemake/snakefmt))

```py
wildcard_constraints:
    barcodes="[A-Z]+",
    sample="Well.*",


refseq = "refseq.fasta"
reads = ["_R1_001", "_R2_001"]


def getsamples():
    import glob

    test = glob.glob("*.fastq")
    print(test)
    samples = []
    for i in test:
        samples.append(i.rsplit("_", 2)[0])
    return samples


def getbarcodes():
    with open("unique.barcodes.txt") as file:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
    return lines


rule all:
    input:
        expand(
            "grepped/{barcodes}{sample}_R1_001.plate.fastq",
            barcodes=getbarcodes(),
            sample=getsamples(),
        ),
        expand(
            "grepped/{barcodes}{sample}_R2_001.plate.fastq",
            barcodes=getbarcodes(),
            sample=getsamples(),
        ),


rule fastq_grep:
    input:
        R1="{sample}_R1_001.fastq",
        R2="{sample}_R2_001.fastq",
    output:
        out1="grepped/{barcodes}{sample}_R1_001.plate.fastq",
        out2="grepped/{barcodes}{sample}_R2_001.plate.fastq",
    shell:
        "fastq-grep -i '{wildcards.barcodes}' {input.R1} > {output.out1} && fastq-grep -i '{wildcards.barcodes}' {input.R2} > {output.out2}"
```

Comment: Happy to hear! You can accept the answer so it is easier for others to recognise it as such.

Comment: Done :) Can I buy you a virtual coffee or something as well? See if you can find a secure way to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @euronion's answer (+1), I prefer to constrain wildcards to match *only* and *exactly* the list of values you expect. This means disabling the regex matching altogether. In your case, I would do something like:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    barcodes='|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in getbarcodes()]),
    sample='|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in getsamples()]),
```

now `{barcodes}` is allowed to match only the values in `getbarcodes()`, whatever they are, and the same for `{sample}`. In my opinion this is better than anticipating what combination of regex a wildcard can take.